# Delete Remote file With @get_file_contents - PHP

Tags: php

I have been trying to delete images from a remote server. I don't want to use a direct link because the server changes depending on the location of the file. I have code like this.

```
$photo["server"] = "http://img1.myserver.com";
$call = @file_get_contents( $photo["server"]."/delete.php?pho_id=".$pho_id."&pag_id=".$pag_id );
```

Is there some reason why this wont work? I send the vars and grab them in the php file. It works fine with a direct browser call but I want to do it from the script. Any ideas why this wont execute the script? And fopen is enabled on my server.

Comment: Error messages are there to help you understand what's wrong with your code - you're suppressing them with the `@` and wondering why it's silently failing

Comment: make sure you have the right PERMISSION to DELETE a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `allow_fopen_url` is on.

What happens when you echo the string? Is it as expected?

What happens when you remove the error suppressor operator (which is bad practice)?

Is the other site yours? Why doesn't it use POST for state changing actions?

There may be cookies in play. Check what cookies the browser has stored when you do it in *direct browser call*.

Comment: Yes allow_open__url is on. Nothing happens when I echo it.  I will remove the suppressor oops. Yes its my site..what do you mean why doesn't it use POST?  Yes there are cookies which also show in firebug if you do a direct call.

Comment: I did find that it was erroring because of a DNS issue and it couldn't find the host of the subdomain. I fixed the DNS problem but it still won't do anything. No errors now that the dns is fixed. It just doesn't do anything. I tried to echo and nothing also. Not sure why it wouldnt work now that its not a hostname issue.

Comment: I guess since it helped me to solve the issue moving the suppressor I'll accept your answer, thanks. I still had issues but figured it out myself finally.